# Write text in existing PDF file

Tags: pdf, genexus

I'm developing a WebPanel with GeneXus.
I need to write text in a specific position of a pdf file uploaded by the user.
How I can do that?
I saw "PDF Tools" library but seems that I can add only images to PDF with this library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote to PDF Tools developer, he helped me and developed a new version of the library with a new method "AddText" available. With this new method it's possible to write text in existing PDF files.
This is the link for download:

[LINK](https://marketplace.genexus.com/product.aspx?pdftools,en)

A code example:

```
&result = &PDFTools.AddText(&PDFIn, &PDFOut, &X, &Y, &PageNumber, &Text, &fontSize)
```

where:

&PDFIn: initial PDF
&PDFOut: output PDF
&X: start X position from left to right
&Y: start Y position from bottom to top
&PageNumber: page number where the text will be included
&Text: text to be inserted in the desired (X,Y) location and the specific PageNumber.
&fontSize: font size